# Brownian Motion and Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I'm confused with this particular problem.

*B(t)* is a BM. 
*M<sub>T</sub>* is the maximum of *B(t)* in [0,T].

What is PDF?

Comment: This is worked out in Karatzas and Shreve's book.  If $T_a$ is the hitting time of $a > 0$, you compute $P(T_a \ge t)$ using the reflection principle; but this is the same as $P(M_t \le a)$.  Then differentiate with respect to $a$ to get the density function.

Comment: Alvin, this is pretty similar to your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228343/brownian-motion-question). Perhaps you can be more specific about what's confusing you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M_t := \sup_{s \leq t} B_s$. As Nate Eldredge already mentioned you have to use the reflection principle:

$$\mathbb{P}[M_t \geq b] \stackrel{\text{Def}}{=} \mathbb{P} \left[\sup_{s \leq t} B_s \geq b \right] = 2 \mathbb{P}[B_t \geq b]$$

It follows that $M_t \sim |B_t|$ since

$$\mathbb{P}[M_t \geq b] = 2\mathbb{P}[B_t \geq b] = \mathbb{P}[B_t \geq b]+\underbrace{\mathbb{P}[-B_t \leq -b]}_{\mathbb{P}[B_t \leq -b]} = \mathbb{P}[|B_t| \geq b]$$

(using the fact that $(-B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a Brownian Motion). Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[M_t \leq b] = 2 \mathbb{P}[0 \leq B_t \leq b] = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi \cdot t}} \cdot \int_0^b \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2t} \right) \, dx \\
\Rightarrow M_t \sim \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi \cdot t}} \cdot \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2t} \right) \cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(x) \, dx$$

Knowing the density function it shouldn't be a problem to calculate the expectation value and variance.